# What is the negation of this sentence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

What is the negation of the following case:

**Case A**: The function $f$ has a unique **rational** fixed point $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the function has:

- multiple rational fixed points or
- no fixed point at all or
- at least one irrational fixed point

Not sure if we can make this more "compact".

Comment: @China: I don't agree with this answer. My point of view is explained in my answer.

Comment: Well, my answer matches better to your 2. than your 1. So in fact we agree on the negation...

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: Thank you. "Unique" refers to "rational fixed point"

Comment: @zwim - I'm not sure to understand your comment: If $f$ has an irrational fixed point and a rational fixed point, then your version of the negation is true (because of point 3) but my version of the negation (see point 2 in my answer) is false. So, your negation and my negation are not equivalent, and only one of them is correct.

Comment: @China - Then the correct negation is in point $(2)$ of my answer, and not in point $(1)$ (or in zwim's answer).

Answer (score 2):

The sentence can be interpreted in two ways, depending on whether "unique" refers to "fixed point" or "rational fixed point":

1. "Unique" refers to "fixed point": The function $f$ has a unique fixed point $a$, and moreover $a$ is rational. The logical form of this sentence is 
   \begin{align}
   \exists a : a \in \mathbb{Q} \land a = f(a) \land \forall z (z = f(z) \to z = a)
   \end{align}
   In this case, the negation is: the function $f$ either has a unique irrational fixed point, or several fixed points, or no fixed points at all (this is equivalent to what @zwim said in his/her [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3312183/288417)).
2. "Unique" refers to "rational fixed point": The function $f$ has exactly one rational fixed point (and possibly many irrational fixed points). The logical form of this sentence is: 
   \begin{align}
   \exists a : a \in \mathbb{Q} \land a = f(a) \land \forall z ((z \in \mathbb{Q} \land z = f(z)) \to z = a)
   \end{align}
   In this case the negation is: the function $f$ has either several rational fixed points or no rational fixed points at all (but it might have irrational fixed points).

Note that the negation of the interpretation $(2)$ is more restrictive than the negation of the interpretation $(1)$: for instance, if $f$ has a irrational fixed point and a rational fixed point, then the negation of $(1)$ is true but the negation of $(2)$ is false.

Unlike @zwim, in my opinion the intended meaning of the sentence should be $(2)$, and not $(1)$, unless contextual information (which is missing in the question of the OP) says differently.